# Insert into mysql but choose when to show ...?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, visible

What I want to do is next:

person makes a new post, let say it is a post for latest news. After form is populated, he/or she have a radio button or check-box to choose to display the latest news right away, or to wait for approval. I tried making a column 'visible' with the type of tinyint ... but no luck, because post is shown no matter if the tinyint value is '0', or '1'. Am i doing this wrong? '0' = false, '1' = true, right?

Example:

```
$headline = $_POST['headline'];
$news = $_POST['news_text'];
$visible = $_POST['visible'];

$query = "INSERT INTO news ( headline, news_text, visible) VALUES ($headline,      $news_text, $visible");

<input type="radio" name="visible" value="0> No
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="1> Yes
```

Seem's a bit dull ... Help is appreciated ...

Comment: Regarding syntax, you need to change your VALUES to: VALUES ($headline, $news, $visible)"; Also, your input values need an ending double-quote.

Comment: `value="0` and `value="1` are missing closing quotes. You are also vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Do not use this code as-is until you've learned about and understand the problem

Comment: ok, thank for pointing that out, bat those are just typo's this is just example to get a feel what is my problem ... with the right syntax, tiniyint with the value 0 still show's row from mysql. So my question is: I'm I doing this wrong ... Thank's

Comment: What does your select statement look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `visible` field is an INT field type (or TINYINT), and only make sure you use 0 or 1 for the value of that field.

So your table should look like this:

```
+----------+-----------+---------+
| headline | text      | visible |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| Test 1   | Text One  | 0       |
| Test 2   | Text Two  | 1       |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Then, when you go to display the articles (only if visibility is 1):

```
SELECT headline, text 
FROM tableName 
WHERE visible = 1
```